# The invocation of the constructor on type 'CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser' that matchs the specified binding constraints threw an exception

Tags: c#, wpf, wix, cefsharp

My C# WPF application uses **CefSharp** to display images. After deployment using WiX Toolset, the following error appeared.

> The invocation of the constructor on type '**CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser**' that matchs the specified binding constraints threw an exception

In the root of the application folder is already containing the following:

```
cef.pak
cef_100_percent.pak
cef_200_percent.pak
CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.Core.dll
CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe
CefSharp.Core.dll
CefSharp.dll
CefSharp.Wpf.dll
d3dcompiler_47.dll
devtools_resources.pak
chrome_elf.dll
icudt.dll
icudtl.dat
libcef.dll
libEGL.dll
libGLESv2.dll
natives_blob.bin
snapshot_blob.bin
```

Why does the CefSharp still not work?

### References

- [Output files description table (Redistribution)](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Output-files-description-table-(Redistribution))
- [CefSharp - GitHub](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp)

Comment: Check your event viewer and the innerexception message to see exactly what's missing.

Comment: I am also getting same issue after publishing application with inbuild VS publish.

Answer (score -1):

may be you need install dotNet Framwork4.5 and VC2013 to your system

Comment: how is it going to help?

Comment: My PC is already installed .Net Framework 4.5, 4.6, 4.7 and VC2012, VC2013 and VC2017.